# No clisp in Debian's repository?

Tags: debian, apt, repository, aptitude, lisp

I want to install [clisp](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=clisp).

My [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList):

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates main contrib

deb http://http.debian.net/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian testing main contrib non-free

deb http://http.debian.net/debian testing-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian testing-updates main contrib non-free
```

`aptitude search clisp` returns nothing.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was removed from testing back in 2014 - https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/comments/2ery81/clisp_removed_from_debian_testing/

It looks like it's currently in sid - https://packages.debian.org/unstable/lisp/